# SQL SUM function doubling the amount it should using multiple tables

Tags: sql, sum

My query below is doubling the amount on the last record it returns. I have 3 tables - activities, bookings and tempbookings. The query needs to list the activities and attached information and pull the total number  (using the SUM) of places booked (as BookingTotal) from the booking table by each activity and then it needs to calculate the same for tempbookings (as tempPlacesReserved) providing the reservedate field inside that table is in the future.

However the first issue is that if there are no records for an activity in the tempbookings table it does not return any records for that activity at all, to get around this i created dummy records in the past so that it still returns the record, but if I can make it so I don't have to do this I would prefer it!

The main issue I have is that on the final record of the returned results it doubles the booking total and the places reserved which of course  makes the whole query useless.

I know that I am doing something wrong I just haven't been able to sort it, I have searched similar issues online but am unable to apply them to my situation correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm aware that normally you wouldn't need to fully label all the paths to the databases, tables and fields as I have but for the program I am planning to use it in I have to do it this way.

Code:

```
SELECT [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityID], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityName], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityDate], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityPlaces], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityPrice], 
    SUM([LeisureActivities].[dbo].[bookings].[bookingPlaces]) AS 'bookingTotal', 
    SUM (CASE WHEN[LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings].[tempReserveDate] > GetDate() THEN [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings].[tempPlaces] ELSE 0 end) AS 'tempPlacesReserved'
FROM [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[bookings], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings]
WHERE ([LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityID]=[LeisureActivities].[dbo].[bookings].[activityID] 
    AND [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityID]=[LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings].[tempActivityID]) 
    AND [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityDate] > GetDate ()
GROUP BY [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityID], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityName], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityDate],
     [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityPlaces], 
    [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities].[activityPrice];
```

Comment: TY bluefeet you were too quick for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is using an `INNER JOIN` between each of the tables so if the `tempBookings` table has no records, you will not return anything.

I would advise that you start to use `JOIN` syntax.  You might also need to use subqueries to get the totals.

```
SELECT a.[activityID], 
    a.[activityName], 
    a.[activityDate], 
    a.[activityPlaces], 
    a.[activityPrice], 
    coalesce(b.bookingTotal, 0) bookingTotal, 
    coalesce(t.tempPlacesReserved, 0) tempPlacesReserved
FROM [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[activities] a
LEFT JOIN
(
  select activityID,
    SUM([bookingPlaces]) AS bookingTotal
  from [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[bookings]
  group by activityID
) b
  ON a.[activityID]=b.[activityID] 
LEFT JOIN
(
  select tempActivityID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [tempReserveDate] > GetDate() THEN [tempPlaces] ELSE 0 end) AS tempPlacesReserved
  from [LeisureActivities].[dbo].[tempbookings]
  group by tempActivityID
) t
  ON a.[activityID]=t.[tempActivityID]
WHERE a.[activityDate] > GetDate();
```

*Note: I am using aliases because it is easier to read*

Comment: This worked a treat - There was a missing ( at the ON function near the bottom but given you're writing this without the date etc. infront of you i'm impressed! Thanks!

Comment: @user2195482 Thanks for the tip on the `(` that is fixed.  I am glad this worked for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use new SQL-92 Join syntax, and make join to tempBookings an outer join.  Also clean up your sql with table aliases. Makes it easier to read. As to why last row has doubled values, I don't know, but on off chance that it is caused by extra dummy records you entered. get rid of them.  That problem is fixed by using outer join to tempBookings. The other possibility is that the join conditions you had to the tempBookings table(t.tempActivityID = a.activityID) is insufficient to guarantee that it will match to only one record in activities table... If, for example, it matches to two records in activities, then the rows from Tempbookings would be repeated twice in the output, (causing the sum to be doubled)

```
SELECT a.activityID, a.activityName, a.activityDate, 
       a.activityPlaces, a.activityPrice, 
       SUM(b.bookingPlaces) bookingTotal, 
       SUM (CASE WHEN t.tempReserveDate > GetDate() 
                 THEN t.tempPlaces ELSE 0 end) tempPlacesReserved
FROM LeisureActivities.dbo.activities a
    Join LeisureActivities.dbo.bookings b
       On b.activityID = a.activityID
    Left Join LeisureActivities.dbo.tempbookings t
       On t.tempActivityID = a.activityID
WHERE a.activityDate > GetDate ()
GROUP BY a.activityID, a.activityName, 
    a.activityDate, a.activityPlaces, 
    a.activityPrice;
```